# Bugs in localization

Tags: issues, localisation

I'm localizing (Italian) some parts of CiviCRM, but I noticed how some terms are not sensible to be translated.
I had a look on the code and I found that these terms are written without the ts() call.

I correct the code, using ts() function, and the problem was solved.

Now I have a little list of these bugs, and my question is: what is the procedure to signal them to the community?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Thanks. Please open an issue on http://issues.civicrm.org/
There you can also add a diff file to an issue.

If you're really hardcore you can fork https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core, add your changes to the git project and do a pull request.